# iOS How to Find Minimum Difference Between the values of Array of Floating/Integer Values

Tags: arrays, swift

I have an array of floating values:

```
let array:[Double] = [2270.87, 2285.15, 2273.49, 2312.89, 2323.07, 2336.14, 2355.09, 2633.0, 2671.34]
```

I need and single line logic using swift higher-order functions or array extension to find the minimum difference value from all differences between the values.

I tried but I'm unable to move further:

```
let array  = [2270.87, 2285.15, 2273.49, 2312.89, 2323.07, 2336.14, 2355.09, 2633.0, 2671.34]
let minDiff = array.map( { *All differences between array of values* } ).reduce(0, min)
```

Actually I am showing these values in a graph. So I want the minimum absolute fluctuation between the values. in the above example like 2323.07 and 2336.14 have minimum fluctuation 10.18.

Comment: Do you mean the minimum of *absolute differences* between all array elements? What would the expected result be in your example, and why?

Comment: Actually I am showing these values in a graph. So I want the minimum absolute fluctuation between the values. in the above example like 2323.07 and 2336.14 have minimum fluctuation 10.18.

Comment: What is “fluctuation”? Do you mean the minimum difference between *consecutive* array elements? Then why do you sort it first? – Please clarify your question!

Comment: @MartinR Yes, sorting is not the way.

Comment: @GurjitSingh the minimum difference between two values in your array is 2.62, which is the result of `abs(2270.87-2273.49)`. So are you looking for the minimum difference between _any two_ elements of the array? Or between two consecutive elements of the array?

Comment: @DávidPásztor I need a minimum difference between two consecutive elements of the array. Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can `zip` two arrays where second one doesn't have first element. Then you can get `abs` value of subtraction value with index *x + 1* from that with index *x*, and using `map()` you can get the minimum value from all of those absolute values.

```
zip(array, array.dropFirst()).map { abs($1 - $0) }.min() // 10.180000000000291
```

Comment: You can avoid the second iteration using min(by:) and get the difference of the resulting tuple. `if let min = zip(array.dropLast(),array.dropFirst()).min(by: {abs($0.0-$0.1)<abs($1.0-$1.1)}) { let dif = abs(min.0-min.1)
}`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to find the minimum absolute difference between two consecutive elements of your array, you can use below extension, which  `map`s over the `indices` of the array, to access 2 consecutive elements at a time.

`dropLast` is important to ensure that we stop iteration before the last element (since we calculate the diff between the penultimate and last element before reaching the last index).

```
extension Array where Element: Comparable, Element: SignedNumeric {
    func minConsecutiveDiff() -> Element? {
        indices.dropLast().map { abs(self[$0] - self[$0+1])}.min()
    }
}

let array:[Double] = [2270.87, 2285.15, 2273.49, 2312.89, 2323.07, 2336.14, 2355.09, 2633.0, 2671.34]
array.minConsecutiveDiff() // 10.18
```

If you were interested in the diff between any two elements of the array, not just consecutive ones, you could get that by first sorting the `Array` and then calculating the diff between the consecutive elements of the sorted array as @MartinR pointed out in comments.

```
extension Array where Element: Comparable, Element: SignedNumeric {
    func minDiff() -> Element? {
        sorted().minConsecutiveDiff()
    }
}
```

Comment: If you sort the array first then it suffices to compute differences of consecutive elements. That should reduce the complexity considerably.

Comment: @MartinR great optimisation, thanks! Updated my answer to utilise that.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way using `forEach`

```
var min: Double = array.max()!
var previous: Double?
array.forEach {
    if let prev = previous, min > abs($0 - prev) {
        min = abs($0 - prev)
    }
    previous = $0
}
```

another option is to use `reduce(into:)` with a tuple

```
let min = array.reduce(into: (Double, Double)(array.first!, 0)) {
    if abs($1 - $0.1) < $0.0 {
        $0.0 = abs($1 - $0.1)
    }
    $0.1 = $1
}.0
```

which both gives 10.18 as the smallest difference.